# An algorithm to stochastically pick the top element of a set with some noise

Tags: python, set, probability

I'd like to find a method (e.g. in python) which given a sorted list, picks the top element with some error epsilon.

One way would be to pick the top element with probability p < 1 and then the 2nd with p' < p and so on with an exponential decay.

Ideally though I'd like a method that takes into account the winning margin of the top element with some noise. I.e:

Given a list [a,b,c,d,e,....] in which a is the largest element, b the second largest and so on,

Pick the top element with probability p < 1, where p depends on the value of a-b, and p' on the value of b-c and so on.

Comment: Almost all of the work here is in defining what you mean by "with some error epsilon", and you are the only one who can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly that, since, if you have *n* elements, you will only have *n-1* differences between consecutive elements. The standard method of doing something similar is [fitness proportionate selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) (link provides code in java and ruby, should be fairly easy to translate to other languages).

For other variants of the idea, look up *selection operators* for *genetic algorithms* (there are various).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to select element `k` with probability proportional to `exp(-(x[k] - x[0])/T)` where `x[0]` is the least element and `T` is a free parameter, analogous to temperature. This is inspired by an analogy to thermodynamics, in which low-energy (small `x[k]`) states are more probable, and high-energy (large `x[k]`) states are possible, but less probable; the effect of temperature is to focus on just the most probable states (`T` near zero) or to select from all the elements with nearly equal probability (large `T`).

The method of simulated annealing is based on this analogy, perhaps you can get some inspiration from that.

EDIT: Note that this method gives nearly-equal probability to elements which have nearly-equal values; from your description, it sounds like that's something you want.

SECOND EDIT: I have it backwards; what I wrote above makes lesser values more probable. Probability proportional to `exp(-(x[n - 1] - x[k])/T)` where `x[n - 1]` is the greatest value makes greater values more probable instead.